# Is there a program on Ubuntu that will work out mortgage repayments?

Tags: software-recommendation, finance

I am lending a family member funds to buy a house (a contract for this loan is being drawn up by my solicitor).

Is there a program on Ubuntu (I have Kylin on my computer) that will automatically show the amount of principal and the amount of interest on each fortnightly deposit made.

For example:

- the loan is for $436,500 @ 4%
- Fortnightly payments are approx $1100

So I need a program that would allow me to see (when I enter each fortnightly amount into the program) the principal component and the interest component.

The amount of the loan that is still owed would also be helpful.

Comment: Is there a program period?  http://alternativeto.net

Comment: The program will need to continue for quite a few years. I am thinking it would be a simplified version of the programs the banks use when someone has a mortgage with them. I am not a whizz on a computer so it would need to be simple. Thank you

Comment: Openoffice calc ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think recommending software in general is hit or miss. It completely depends on user preferences and experience with the type of software you are looking for.

I would recommend doing some personal research on mortgage linux calculator programs or just general programs for mortgage payment calculations and using alternativeto.net to find a linux like substitute.

After a quick search seems others recommend [Mortgage loan calculator](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Office/Finance/Mortgage-Loan-Calculator-39955.shtml)

Have a good one ; )